# How to manage Signing certificates for multiple locations

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I am working for a remote client (They're in US and we're in Canada) and we are developing a Windows client.  We are going to have them purchase an EV certificate so we can digitally sign the app.
We've done this in the past with non-EV certificated but from what I've read, EV certificates keys come on a physical USB device. I contacted ComodoSSL to see if we can get more than one as I see there being a big risk (And cost) for shipping the key back and forth. They said that can only issue one.
I will be the only one using the key to sign the app but I don't feel comfortable with the client not having a backup.
I'm sure I'm not the only one to have run into this situation and was looking for some feedback as to how others handle this without purchasing an HSM?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to rely on an online signing service instead of a USB token, such as AWS Key Management Service, Azure KeyVault, Google Cloud HSM, DigiCert ONE or SSL.com eSigner. The key is stored in the cloud and each team has its own credentials to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I decided to move away from MS ClickOnce installer and move to a sparkle based deployment and because of that I don't have to worry about signing the manifest which was the biggest hassle.